# How to pass arguments (for FEED_URI) to Scrapy spider's instane for dynamically naming output file

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to send arguments to spider and get output (json, csv) named accordingly to arguments.
F.e.,
 
$ scrapy crawl spider_name -a category=category1 -a subcategory=subcategory1 
and I want to get: 
category1_subcategory1.json (or csv, it doesn't matter).
I mean I need exactly json name as arguments for spider.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'my_spider'
# how can I get to this place ?
customs_settings = {
  'FEED_URI' : 'some_name.json'
 }
def __init__(self, category, subcategory, *args, **kwargs):

    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.category = category
    self.subcategory = subcategory
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [Storage URI parameters](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters) section in the docs? Especially  _The storage URI can also contain parameters that get replaced when the feed is being created.(...) Any other named parameter gets replaced by the spider attribute of the same name. For example, %(site_id)s would get replaced by the spider.site_id attribute the moment the feed is being created._

Comment: I read docs. Offcourse, I missed something, but I don't find way to link arguments with FEED_URI attribute

Comment: Try for example `FEED_URI='%(category)_%(subcategory).json'`

Answer (score 6):

You can get those parameters from `kwargs` of `__init__` and use in `FEED_URI` like this:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    custom_settings = {
      'FEED_URI' : '%(category)s_%(subcategory)s.json'
     }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.category = kwargs.pop('category', '')
        self.subcategory = kwargs.pop('subcategory', '')
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters

Comment: How do you pass values from and to category and subcategory to __init__? I called scrapy.Request to def parse(self, response) but the process didn't go through the def parse(self, response) at all.