# Pass Spider Arguments in custom_settings in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Random'
    start_urls = ["http://someRandomsite.aspx"]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'file://%(data_dir_path)s/data.csv',
        'FEED_TEMPDIR': '%(raw_dir_path)s'
    }

    def __init__(self, data_dir_path='/home/data', raw_dir_path='/home/raw', url=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data_dir_path = data_dir_path
        self.raw_dir_path = raw_dir_path
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to pass the arguments in the custom settings but it doesn't show in Overridden Settings.

I followed this link [How to pass arguments (for FEED_URI) to Scrapy spider's instane for dynamically naming output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871605/how-to-pass-arguments-for-feed-uri-to-scrapy-spiders-instane-for-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show in override settings, but it does apply. When I use your code I get this in the log:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/data'
```

Which indicates that it was trying to use that for the feed path.

Comment: ```print(self.settings.get('FEED_URI'))``` 
Doing this inside parse function results into this 
```file://%(data_dir_path)s/data.csv```

Comment: Is something actually broken, or are you just concerned about it not showing? Those string replacements happen as part of the [feed exporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters), not as a pre-processing of the custom settings. So technically, the setting value you see is correct because that is the stored setting.

Comment: Also, it doesn't actually *replace* the value within the `custom_settings` dictionary. It *[copies](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L183)* the value, and then reformats it  [elsewhere](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L213). So in effect you will never see that from within the spider.

Comment: I want to store the scraped data within a directory and raw_data within another which are passed as arguments or use the default value as given in init function. But the data is not getting stored in the directory specified.

Comment: How are you running your spider? Your code works fine for me. I can run it as `scrapy runspider spider.py` and it will try to use `/home/data`. Or I can run it like `scrapy runspider spider.py -a data_dir_path=/tmp` (to override the argument) and it stores a `data.csv` file in the correct location. What specific problems are you experiencing? Where does your `data.csv` file get saved? Or do you get an error?

Comment: The file should start being populated already while the spider is running. But not immediately, you have to wait a little bit. Does your log show that it is finding the items you expect?

Comment: Thanks. I also want to make a post request to a specified url after every 5 minutes to send the stats. Where should be the function called??

Comment: Ask that in a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707698/scrapy-send-stats-to-a-url-passed-as-argument-as-a-post-request-every-5-minutes

Comment: ```'HTTPCACHE_DIR': '../%(raw_dir_path)s/'``` I have a setting like this but this isn't working. It stores the cache in a folder named ```%(raw_dir_path)s``` in root directory of project. The default value of %(raw_dir_path)s is 'raw', as I want the cache in a folder named raw in Root directory of project

Comment: @JigarChavada Note that the variable replacement happens only in the **feed export** system. That HTTP cache variable is not used there, so it won't get the replacement. You need to rather add custom settings and update it in `__init__`. But this is an unrelated question, so rather ask a different one about it.