# Scrapy send stats to a URL passed as argument as a POST request every 5 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I need to send the crawler stats to a URL which is passed on as a spider argument. I need to make a POST request at regular intervals of 5 minutes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to write an extension that simply makes a post request every 5 minutes.
You can make these requests either using scrapy's own mechanisms (e.g. `engine.download()`), or you can use a different async http client (e.g. [treq](https://treq.readthedocs.io/))

If you're not sure how to structure your extension, you can take a look at [logstats.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/logstats.py) which does a similar thing, except not logging over http.

Since you're writing an extension anyway, I'd recommend making the url and interval settings, but that choice is up to you.